# Highlight text from jdt java text editor using line numbers in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to write an eclipse plugin which highlights some text in java editor after user save the text (ResourceChangeListener). I am implementing **ILightweightLabelDecorator** and extending **BaseLabelProvider**, The method

```
public void decorate(Object arg0, IDecoration arg1)
```

getting called but I am getting Objects of type org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.*
e.g org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageDeclaration.
I need line numbers from that object so I can highlight that text.
    ASTNode object has a property to get the position (line numbers) but I am not getting that one. How can I get ASTNode from org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.* 
 objects?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PackageDeclaration` is part of the JDT [Java Model](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) which is a lighter weight version of the AST used by a lot of the Java code. As such it isn't related to `ASTNode`.

Many Java Model objects (including `PackageDeclaration`) implement `ISourceReference` which tells you about the source code. This includes `getSource` and `getSourceRange` methods.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following method for accessing line number,

```
    private int getLineNumberInSource(SourceRefElement member) throws 
JavaModelException { 
    if (member == null || !member.exists()) { 
        return -1; 
    } 
    ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = member.getCompilationUnit(); 
    if (compilationUnit == null) { 
        return -1; 
    } 
    String fullSource = compilationUnit.getBuffer().getContents(); 
    if (fullSource == null) { 
        return -1; 
    } 
    ISourceRange nameRange = member.getNameRange(); 
    if (nameRange == null) { 
        return -1; 
    } 
    String string2 = fullSource.substring(0, nameRange.getOffset()); 
    return 
            string2.split(compilationUnit.findRecommendedLineSeparator()).length; 
}
```